# Mongoose retrieving data without _id field

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I would like to retrieve some data from a Mongoose setting in my Node.js application. I noticed that no matter what I write as field selection, I always get the `_id` field. Is there a way not to fetch it?
This is how I do right now:

```
Transaction.find({username : user.username}, ['uniqueId', 'timeout', 'confirmation_link', 'item_name'], function(err, txs){
        console.log("user : " + user.username + " with txs: " + txs);
        callback(txs);
});
```

And logs me the results which contain the `_id` field.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

`_id` must be specifically excluded. For example,

```
Transaction.find({username : user.username}, { '_id': 0, 'uniqueId' :1, 'timeout': 1, 'confirmation_link': 1, 'item_name': 1}, function(err, txs){
  console.log("user : " + user.username + " with txs: " + txs);
  callback(txs);
});
```

Comment: Can you exclude _id and still keep id? I noticed that id is a virtual field. I want to have id but exclude _id in my REST api. For now, when I exclude _id, id becomes null

Comment: We can exclude nested _id also(e:g cars._id: 0)

Comment: How to exclude _id in subdocs, the above command excludes it from outer doc but not from subdocs.

Comment: @jazeb007 
Transaction.find({}).select("-_id").populate({path:"product",select:"-_id"})
this should exclude '_id' from docs and subdocs.

Answer (score 126):

Another way is to use text argument with prefix `-` which will exclude this or that field from the result:

```
Entity.find({ ... }, '-_id field1 field2', function(err, entity) {
    console.log(entity);  // { field1: '...', field2: '...' }
});
```

Comment: Awesome. I notice also that if you use '-_id' Mongoose will return all fields except _id. Marvellous.

Comment: Excellent! I used it like:

const publicUserValues = ['-_id', 'name', 'website', 'bio'];
const user = await User.findOne({ username }, publicUserValues).exec();

Answer (score 23):

Another approach:

- Augment the  `.toJSON()` of the schema that it deletes the `_id` and the `__v` fields
- Call `.toJSON()` on all DB objects sent to client
- Extra benefit #1: you can use `item.id === 'something'` because `typeof id === 'string'`, not `ObjectId`.
- Extra benefit #2: When you got gan object back from the client and you want to search / update then you don't have to manually delete `_id` because there is none, just an `id` which is ignored.

Augmenting JSON:

```
mySchema.set('toJSON', {
    virtuals: true,
    transform: (doc, ret, options) => {
        delete ret.__v;
        ret.id = ret._id.toString();
        delete ret._id;
    },
});
```

So you can use:

```
 let item = (await MyCollection.findOne({/* search */}).exec()).toJSON();
 if (item.id === 'someString') return item;
```

I know it's ugly. But it's the best bad idea that I have so far.

Answer (score 10):

In 5.2.13 version of Mongoose (Sept 2018)- using the query builder approach the same can be converted to

```
async function getUserDetails(user) {
    try {
        if (!user || !user.name) return;
        const result = await Transaction.
        find({username : user.username}).
        select('uniqueId timeout confirmation_link item_name -_id'); 
        // Adding minus sign before the _id (like -_id) in the select string unselects the _id which is sent by default. 
        console.log(result);
    } catch(ex) {
        return ex
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing you can do is something like this:

```
Transaction.find({username : user.username}, {_id: 0}, (err, txs) => {
    // the return document won't contain _id field
    // callback function body
}
```

Just remember that in the second object passed in the find()-

1. Pass 0 as the value to the specific key that you wish not to fetch
   from the mongodb database.
2. Pass 1 as the value when you wish to
   fetch from the mongodb database.