# mongodb mongoose find - how do I get applicable strings as result?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to use data from my MongoDB for displaying on HTML code via Node.js. So far, I know how to insert information from a HTML5 formular into my MongoDB and how I read out this information - but the result of my `find()` is like:

```
[ { name: 'Mr. Banana', _id: 123aclongvalueinHEX001c000001 } ]
```

This is the simple result example display on my `node.exe` cmdshell of the function:

```
People.find(
    {},
    ['name'],
    function(err, docs) {
        if (!err){ 
            console.log(docs);
        }
        else { throw err;}
    }
);
```

`People` is the Mongoose schema and has some attributes, in this example I am only searching for all names with only one entity saved in `People`.

So the question is, and I feel like searching for it forever, how do I only extract `Mr. Banana` without the whole `[{ name: and id}]` - thing? I suppose there is some function or option for it, but I just can't find it! I could invent a function to trim it by leftstr etc. this would be my emergency solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the hint that mongoose has functions called querystreams. That leads to my solution.

```
var Bericht = new Schema({
    name     : String
  , mail     : String
  , standort : String
  , betreff  : String
  , inhalt   : String
  , datum    : Date
});
var Bericht = mongoose.model('Bericht', Bericht);

  var stream = Bericht.find().stream()
  , names = []
  , mails = []
  , standorts = []
  , betreffs = []
  , inhalts = []
  , datums = []
  , i=0;

function closeHandler() {
    function closeHandler() {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(names));
    };
     stream.on('data', function (doc) {
            if (doc.name) {
        names.push(doc.name);
        mails.push(doc.mail);
        standorts.push(doc.standort);
        betreffs.push(doc.betreff);
        inhalts.push(doc.inhalt);
        datums.push(doc.datum);
      }
    })
    stream.on('close', closeHandler)
```

My schema has more than names, in this case 6 attributes. After using the stream.on function, I got everything out of my database into an array like mails[1] is the mail of the second entry in my mongodb. With that, I can easily display the whole content of my database in a html by using functions. Maybe this is too much, but due of liking this board, I'll complete this thread.

With this function, you are building a simple table of all names as return value:

```
    function namestable(){
        value = "<table border='1'><tr><th>Namen</th></tr>"
        for(var i=0;i<names.length;i++){
    value+="<tr><td>"+names[i]+"</td>";
        ;}
        value+="</table>";
    return value;
    }
```

So you just have to add this function into your nodejs, when you are building the html code:

```
var body = '<html>'+
    '<head>'+
    '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; '+
    'charset=UTF-8" />'+
    '</head>'+
    '<body>'+
    '<form action="/upload" method="post">'+
    namestable()+
    '<input type="submit" value="Hario" />'+
    '</form>'+
    '</body>'+
    '</html>';

        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        response.write(body);
        response.end();
```

I like :)

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to output the `name` property of the first document in your results:

```
console.log(docs[0].name);
```

If you want to prevent the `_id` from even being included in the returned docs, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598505/mongoose-retrieving-data-without-id-field).

Comment: Hi,thanks for your fast answer, but this leads to the output "undefined". I thought myself that docs.name could give me just the info of the attribute name, but I am wrong and so you are it seems. But the direction you are heading, I like ;)

Comment: If I do "console.log(docs[0]);" there will be only the value "_id: xxx...xxx" so it seems that there is no attribute name. When I do "console.log(docs);", the result is "[ { name: 'Mr. Banana', _id: 123aclongvalueinHEX001c000001 } ]" so name gets lost by invoking a single entry. Weird. But! If I do "console.log(docs.name);" the result is also undefined... Quite annoying.

Comment: I've seen some weird behavior like that when running inside a cmdshell, and I see that's what you're using.  Try putting your program into a file and running it outside the shell.

Comment: @JohnnyHK I too am getting a string for a result. It seems like i need to do `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(docs[0]));` but i do not know why. Any thoughts?