# Exclude mongoose table filed in nested object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I have simple Schema I am using this method to get all fields without the `_id` field:

```
var testSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    field1: String
});

testSchema.find({}, { _id: 0, _v: 0}, function(...));
```

But when I have a nested object, its `_id`  field appears when I query it.

How can I do the same - hide the `_id` filed for nested objects?

```
var anotherSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    field2: String,
    testField: [testSchema]
});

anotherSchema.find({}, { ???? }, function(...));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution. Based on alternative syntax for excluding fields from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24389009/3306465

This is working for me:

```
anotherSchema.find({}, '-_id -testField._id', function(...))
```

Comment: for some reason this is not working for me :/. It only removes the first one but  not the second argument

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```js
anotherSchema.find({}, { 'testField._id': 0 })
```

Comment: That gives me error of `SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`