# node.js - Bad ordering in POST request using Postman

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mean

I'm learning node and I use Postman to execute those request with parameters in the body.

For the router: router.post('/locations', ctrlLocations.locationsCreate);
here is the controller:

```
module.exports.locationsCreate = function (req, res) {
    Loc.create({
        name: req.body.name,
        address: req.body.address,
        facilities: req.body.facilities.split(","),
        coords: [parseFloat(req.body.lng), parseFloat(req.body.lat)],
        openingTimes: [{
            days: req.body.days1,
            opening: req.body.opening1,
            closing: req.body.closing1,
            closed: req.body.closed1,
        },{
            days: req.body.days2,
            opening: req.body.opening2,
            closing: req.body.closing2,
            closed: req.body.closed2,
        }]
    },
    function(err, location){
        if(err){
            sendJSONresponse(res, 400, err);
        } else{
            sendJSONresponse(res, 201, location);
        }
    }); 
};
```

Here you can see my DB model for 'locations':

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var openingTimeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    days: {type: String, required: true},
    opening: String,
    closing: String,
    closed: {type: Boolean, required: true}
});

var reviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    author: {type: String, required: true},
    rating: {type: Number, required: true, min: 0, max: 5},
    reviewText: {type: String, required: true},
    createdOn: {type: Date, "default": Date.now}
});

var locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String},
    address: String,
    rating: {type: Number, "default":0, min: 0,  max: 5},
    facilities: [String],
    coords: {type: [Number], index:'2ndsphere'},
    openingTimes: [openingTimeSchema],
    reviews: [reviewSchema]
});

mongoose.model('Location', locationSchema);
```

I don't have any problem to create a new 'location' by using mongodb console, but I'm facing problems when using Postman: the response sent change the order of some of the 'fields' and add unwanted ids to 'opening times'.

Here the x-www-form-urlencoded request as a bulk edit:

```
name:Paquito's Bar
address:41 Lower Brook St, Reading RG1 2AQ, UK
rating:4.5
facilities:WiFi, Coffe, Sexy Staff
lng:-0.9722977
lat:51.4494778
days1:Monday -Friday
opening1:8:00am
closing1:5:00pm
closed1:false
days2:Saturday - Sunday
opening2:10:00am
closing2:12:00pm
closed2:false
```

And here the result:

```
{
  "__v": 0,
  "name": "Paquito's Bar",
  "address": "41 Lower Brook St, Reading RG1 2AQ, UK",
  "_id": "5774ecf8bcdead7c368a7648",
  "reviews": [],
  "openingTimes": [
    {
      "days": "Monday -Friday",
      "opening": "8:00am",
      "closing": "5:00pm",
      "closed": false,
      "_id": "5774ecf8bcdead7c368a764a"
    },
    {
      "days": "Saturday - Sunday",
      "opening": "10:00am",
      "closing": "12:00pm",
      "closed": false,
      "_id": "5774ecf8bcdead7c368a7649"
    }
  ],
  "coords": [
    -0.9722977,
    51.4494778
  ],
  "facilities": [
    "WiFi",
    " Coffe",
    " Sexy Staff"
  ],
  "rating": 0
}
```

I'm creating  here documents for the API, and as you can see the ordering is bad, and I don't want _id's in the opening times: I rather force the id creation when is needed via code than automatically creation.

Maybe there's a better way to use Postman... Any help will be useful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think your problem is with postman - its mongoose/mongo that is adding the _id. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598505/mongoose-retrieving-data-without-id-field

Comment: I can't discard mongoose, but i think at least mongo is not, as this query: `code`// Save query for new Location
db.locations.save({
 name: 'Starcups',
 address: '125 High Street, Reading, RG6 1PS',
 rating: 3,
 facilities: ['Hot drinks', 'Food', 'Premium wifi'],
 coords: [-0.9690884, 51.455041],
 openingTimes: [{
  days: 'Monday - Friday',
  opening: '7:00am',
  closing: '7:00pm',
  closed: false
 }, {
  days: 'Saturday',
  opening: '8:00am',
  closing: '5:00pm',
  closed: false
 }, {
  days: 'Sunday',
  closed: true
 }]
})`code` is executing very well

Comment: I've read the post you mention, and OK, you can exclude when you find, but the thing here is to be i harmony with the db mode, where opening times are properties of a location, so they should be part of the document, and not subdocuments (if I got it well mongoose create id's for each document, but shouldn't create when we're talking about the 'object' itself). Tanks, anyway!

Answer (score 0):

The order of "fields" is NOT GARAUNTEED in javascript and you should never ever depend on it.

About the "ids" - you said to mongoose that in `openingTimes` is array of another schema, therefore it behaves with it like that.

If openingTimes is nested document, you should define it as nested document, for example like this

```
var locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String},
    address: String,
    rating: {type: Number, "default":0, min: 0,  max: 5},
    facilities: [String],
    coords: {type: [Number], index:'2ndsphere'},
    openingTimes: [{
        days: {type: String, required: true},
        opening: String,
        closing: String,
        closed: {type: Boolean, required: true}
    }],
    reviews: [reviewSchema]
});
```

Comment: Right, with opening times, but I think there has to be away to: 1) Avoid creating id and 2) save the document with the order established in the model.

Comment: @AtomicNation - Schema is collection in MongoDB. Collection cant be without _id in MongoDB. And neither MongoDB neither Javascript DOES NOT GARAUNTEE the order of fields. Never. Ever. Therefore you should not too, or you would be disapointed :). Google it - "mongodb order fields"

Comment: I see...this is just weird to me, but I guess that while it works, everybody's happy! Thank you everyone for your help!