# _id or another field from JSON response Node js not excluded

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I want to exclude default _id or any one of the two fields (time and count) while fetching the data result from JSON API in my node-express app. I tried several ways to do so but still the data shows the field that I marked as excluded in GET response. In my code below, I used _Id as sample, but similar problem persists for every field of my database. Here are some of the ways I figured out that didn't worked:

```
exports.get_all_clothing = (req, res, next) => {
    Clothing.find({}, {projection:{_id: 0}})
    .exec()
    .then(docs => {
        console.log(docs);
        res.status(200).json(docs);
    })       

      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
          error: err
        });
      });
}
                             AND

exports.get_all_clothing = (req, res, next) => {
    Clothing
    .find({}).project({ _id: 0 })
    .exec()
    .then(docs => {
        console.log(docs);
        res.status(200).json(docs);
    })       

      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
          error: err
        });
      });
}
                           AND

exports.get_all_clothing = (req, res, next) => {
    Clothing.find('-_id')
    .exec()
    .then(docs => {
        console.log(docs);
        res.status(200).json(docs);
    })       

      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
          error: err
        });
      });
}
```

Everytime I keep getting the result as

```
[ { _id: 5cb73
    time: '656
    count: 43,
    __v: 0 }, 
  { _id: 5cb73
    time: '155
    count: 60,
    __v: 0 }, 
  { _id: 5cb73
    time: '155
    count: 56,
    __v: 0 }, ....]
```

Please help out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose retrieving data without \_id field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598505/mongoose-retrieving-data-without-id-field)

Comment: I tried many answers suggested here but none of them seems to work, hence I posted again with all possible solutions I tried.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
exports.get_all_tweets = (req, res, next) => {
    Clothing.find({}, {_id: 0})
    .exec()
    .then(docs => {
        console.log(docs);
        res.status(200).json(docs);
    })       

      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
          error: err
        });
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use query.select to get your desired results.

```
exports.get_all_tweets = (req, res, next) => {
    Clothing.find()
    .select('-_id')
    .then(docs => {
        console.log(docs);
        res.status(200).json(docs);
    })       

      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
          error: err
        });
      });
}
```

Comment: Still getting the _id