# How can I remove a property of object from an array in Mongoose? !Important

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

Doc -

```
const array =   [
  {
    user: new ObjectId("627913922ae9a8cb7a368326"),
    name: 'Name1',
    balance: 0,
    _id: new ObjectId("627913a92ae9a8cb7a36832e")
  },
  {
    user: new ObjectId("6278b20657cadb3b9a62a50e"),
    name: 'Name2',
    balance: 0,
    _id: new ObjectId("6279133b2ae9a8cb7a368314")
  },
  {
    user: new ObjectId("627913692ae9a8cb7a368319"),
    name: 'Name3',
    balance: 0,
    _id: new ObjectId("627913872ae9a8cb7a368321")
  },
  {
    user: new ObjectId("6278b24e57cadb3b9a62a513"),
    name: 'Name4',
    balance: 0,
    _id: new ObjectId("6278b41ab18ff3dff84781bd")
  }
]
```

Here, I want to remove the "_id" from all the objects in the array

I tried to use delete property but it didn't work

```
array.forEach(object=>delete object._id)
```

And When I tried the same `array.forEach(object=>delete object._id)` by removing **new ObjectId** in **_id** property of object in array it worked fine!

But as I am fetching this array from MongoDb,I can't remove this  **new ObjectId** manually, So I need to fix this!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598505/mongoose-retrieving-data-without-id-field

Comment: setting _id to 0 will remove it from the result. db.yourCollectionName.find({},{_id:0});

Comment: `Model.find().select("-_id")`

Comment: What is your problem you want to deselect the `_id` from the DB response or this array is part of one document and you don't want the id's to be generated there in the first place??

Answer (score 0):

Here, I got my answer

In the array

```
    const array =   [
  {
    user: new ObjectId("627913922ae9a8cb7a368326"),
    name: 'Name1',
    balance: 0,
    _id: new ObjectId("627913a92ae9a8cb7a36832e")
  },
  {
    user: new ObjectId("6278b20657cadb3b9a62a50e"),
    name: 'Name2',
    balance: 0,
    _id: new ObjectId("6279133b2ae9a8cb7a368314")
  },
  {
    user: new ObjectId("627913692ae9a8cb7a368319"),
    name: 'Name3',
    balance: 0,
    _id: new ObjectId("627913872ae9a8cb7a368321")
  },
  {
    user: new ObjectId("6278b24e57cadb3b9a62a513"),
    name: 'Name4',
    balance: 0,
    _id: new ObjectId("6278b41ab18ff3dff84781bd")
  }
]
```

I tried to use .map() and it did my work

```
let list = []

array.map((object)=>{
    list.push({user: object.user,name: object.name,balance: object.balance})
})

console.log(list);
```